# Need input on Standalone SSRS SQL Server 2016 Report Builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to create reports using the Standalone Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Report Builder for then later use the report with ASP.NET Webform deployed-published?

Please pardon my Ignorance, I've created reports using the built in SSRS in Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 and published with Webform to the hosting or dedicated server that works fine, but I am not sure that I could do the same creating the report using the Standalone SSRS 2016 and using it with my published ASP.NET WEB Form.

Thanks

Comment: The new Report Builder creates .RDL reports, the same .RDLs as contained in the Report Server solutions in VS 2008 and 2010.

Comment: And .RDL files require Report Server.  This is different from .RDLC files that can be rendered in ASP.NET without Report Server.

Answer (score 0):

While it is correct that rdl reports require report server?

If report server is available, then the client side rdl report viewer can be pointed to such reports.

And in most cases, a rdl report CAN be imported into the vs project, renamed as rdlc. Then some settings (such as processing mode = local = true) have to be changed.

So, such reports created with the reporting tools can be used in your asp.net webforms application, but "some" changes are required.

The changes and how to use such reports it outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-webforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver16